# log2 for BigInteger in Java

Tags: java

Wondering if there is an API to calculate `log_2` directly? Here is my current code, which I transfer `log_2(N)` to be `log_e(N)/log_e(2)`.

BTW, it seems for normal Java Double type, there is no method to calculate `log_2(double_value)` directly?

**My code in Java**,

```
BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(16);
BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.log(x.longValue()) / Math.log(2)));
System.out.println(y.doubleValue()); // return 4.0 as expected
```

Comment: "`Math.log(x.longValue())`" note that `log` takes a double, so you may as well use `x.doubleValue()` here, as it will be widened anyway.

Comment: @AndyTurner, agree and nice catch. BTW, do you know if there is an API to calculate log_2 directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is built in to the `BigInteger` API. From the Javadoc:

> ```
> public int bitLength()
> ```
>
> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`, excluding a sign bit. For positive `BigInteger`s, this is equivalent to the number of bits in the ordinary binary representation. (Computes `(ceil(log2(this < 0 ? -this : this+1)))`.)

Comment: Hi Jim, nice method and vote up. Actually I am asking a more general question, suppose if want to calculate `log_x`, where `x` could be any number like `2,3,4,...`, then how do you calculate? I think `bigLength()` could only handle case of exponential of `2`, right?

Comment: The only general method is the one you outlined.  Convert to `double` and do the calculation there.  `BigInteger` can represent values outside the range of `double` so you may lose information in extreme cases.

Comment: Thanks Jim, from your comments -- " may lose information in extreme cases", this is exactly my concern. Actually I am a bit surprised `BigInteger`  does not provide a way to do log for any given base (but at the same time, a lot of other math computation are provided for `BigInteger`, not sure why `log` is missing). Any thoughts?

Comment: BTW, Jim, it seems for double itself, it does not have a solution to calculate log for a general base?

Comment: There's no need as `logBaseN(x) == log(x)/log(base)` as you showed in your code.  As to the lack of `log` in `BigInteger`... you'd have to ask the language designers.

Comment: BigInteger.valueOf(16).bitLength() returns 5 but log2(16) is 4??? Should I subtract one?

Comment: `2^4` equals `16` which has 5 bits - `10000`.  The suggestion to use `log(x)` is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want partial bits:

```
const twoToThe50th = Math.pow(2, 50);
const log2BigInt = (x: bigint) => {
  let log = 0;
  while (x > twoToThe50th) {
    // Shift by 6 bytes to right to stay on byte boundaries
    x = x >> BigInt(48);
    log += 48;
  }
  // x is now small enough to be a Number, which we
  // can pass to JavaScript's built in log2 function
  return log + Math.log2(Number(x));
}
```

Comment: The question asked for an answer in Java. It appears that you submitted an answer in CoffeeScript. For much better performance, consider doing a binary search algorithm. Also, numbers can store 2**1024. Also, literals flow better with performance in JIT compilation than variables, so consider inlining twoToThe50th with its literal value. Also, repeatedly creating a new `BigInt` in the middle of a tight loop is a performance sinkhole. Also, consider applying integer optimizations to the log variable: `log = log + 48 |0;`. Also, consider localizing `Math.log2` and `Number`. I hope this helps